# How to set up Russian Cyrillic Times New Roman font in PdfLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, cyrillic, metafont, russian

I need to set up Russian Cyrillic Times New Roman font in PdfLaTeX for whole document.

My system:
— Windows 10;
— TeXStudio;
— TeXLive;

What I have already tried:

**1)** I installed the Russian Cyrillic font Times New Roman with XeLaTeX.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
```

It worked for me but in another project.

**2)** I installed the Times font for PdfLaTeX.

```
\usepackage{tempora}
```

But this is the Times font, not Times New Roman.

**3)** I found the font Times New Roman for the PdfLaTeX.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

But he works for me only with the English text. With the Russian-language text does not work, it produces an error:

```
Command \cyrp unavailable in encoding T1.
```

A sample of my code on which I get the above error:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%%% Page
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=20mm, right=15mm}

\begin{document}
    This is any text in English. Works fine.

    Below is written the Russian text, on which I get an error.

    Это не работающий русский текст. Выдаёт ошибку при компиляции. 5

\end{document}
```

**Update:** If I use

```
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

instead

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

then I do not get an error. But the font that I have is not the Times or Times New Roman.

Comment: There is *no* free Times New Roman (aka Monotype Times) for `pdflatex`, as far as I know. The available fonts are clones of (Linotype) Times.

Comment: What are the Times New Roman clones?

Comment: `T1`  is not suited for cyrillic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Tempora, which however is based on (Linotype) Times Roman rather than (Monotype) Times New Roman. There's no free clone of the latter available in TeX distributions, as far as I know.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

%%% Page
\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is any text in English. Works fine.
\end{otherlanguage*}

Это не работающий русский текст. Выдаёт ошибку при компиляции. 5

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need math, you can also add `\usepackage{newtxmath}`.

The same with Times New Roman and XeLaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\frenchspacing

%%% Page
\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is any text in English. Works fine.
\end{otherlanguage*}

Это не работающий русский текст. Выдаёт ошибку при компиляции. 5

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your font does not look much like Times New Roman. I think that the checking committee will notice that the font is not the one. I'll wait another couple of days. There may be other solutions. But still I will prepare for rewriting the code under XeLaTeX. Thank you for your desire to help.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in the egreg example LH font is loaded.

Comment: @ERAFY Sorry, I posted the wrong image

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Fixed, I just used the wrong image

Comment: What do you have in mind with your suggestion to use `\usepackage{newtxmath}`?

Comment: @JonathanW. It provides math symbols compatible with Times.